# How to move a button from one div to another when clicked in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've placed the following buttons within a div

```
const [state, setstate] = useState([]);

getButtonsUsingMap(){
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];  
return arr.map((num) => {
    return (
        <button
            key={num}
            className="buttons"
            onClick={(e) => {
                state.push(num);
            }}
        >
            {num}
        </button>
    );
});
}
```

Currently my two divs look like this:

```
function App(){
return (
    <>
      <div className="left" style={{ float: "left" }}>
        {getButtonsUsingMap()}
      </div>
      <div className="right" style={{ float: "right" }}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

When those buttons are clicked, I want them to move to another div. And when the button is clicked on the other div, the button has to come back to the original div.I found a solution but it involves document.getElementById(). But I believe that it is not a good thing to do in reactjs. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "move"? Would it be sufficient if a button appears in the other div, and this button disappears when this button is clicked?

Comment: @HanchenJiang Yes, thats sufficient

Comment: There are no `<div>` shown. Hard to help without a [mre]. A better explanation of how this is supposed to work would also help when you provide the proper document structure

Comment: @charlietfl return (
    <>
      <div className="left" style={{ float: "left" }}>
        {getButtonsUsingMap()}
      </div>
      <div className="right" style={{ float: "right" }}></div>
      <div style={{ clear: "both" }}>Below</div>
    </>
  );
}     The component renders the button. But I don't want to render directly. Render only when clicked. That's why I didn't include that part

Comment: Code dumps in unformatted comments are very hard to work with. [edit] the question instead so all readers can easily see the code and the full explanation

Comment: @charlietfl I've edited the question. Kindly verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a state which can contain the numbers, and add data ids to the divs. Then in your click handler you can pick out the button number and the div id, and then reset the state.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ data, setData ] = useState({
    divOne: [1, 2 , 3, 4, 5],
    divTwo: []
  });

  function handleClick(e) {
    const { parentNode, nodeName } = e.target;

    if (nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
      const { num } = e.target.dataset;
      const { id } = parentNode.dataset;
      const remaining = data[id].filter(el => el !== +num);
      if (id === 'divOne') {
        setData({
          divOne: remaining,
          divTwo: [...data.divTwo, +num].sort()
        });
      }
      if (id === 'divTwo') {
        setData({
          divOne: [...data.divOne, +num].sort(),
          divTwo: remaining
        });
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      <div data-id="divOne" className="red">
        {data.divOne.map(el => {
          return (
            <button data-num={el}>
              Click {el}
            </button>
          )
        })}
      </div>
      <div data-id="divTwo" className="blue">
        {data.divTwo.map(el => {
          return (
            <button data-num={el}>
              Click {el}
            </button>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

};

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example arr={arr} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
div { padding: 1em; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: how can I access individual buttons in this if I have to attach some event handlers?

Comment: And it throws an error when I accidently click the area where the button was previously located. Is it possible to rectify it sir?

Comment: I've fixed the error, but I don't really know what your first question means.

Comment: I was asking about how to access the individual buttons. But I was able to find it by myself. Thank you for your precious answer